# Multiple Duplicate Querys overloading Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, database

We are currently experiencing an issue were our site runs fine for about 3 hours, but then our MySQL server crashes as a result of one query being run up to 300 times at once.

The query is the following.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id=10
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) = '4') AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1')
```

The only variation is the category ID. Reindexing catalog_category_products does fix the issue for a short period, but eventually, the same problem persists.

Our MYSQL is running on an r4.x2large instance running MariaDB 10.2

Any help or feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 2.6 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful info, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_product_entity; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_category_product_index_store1; C) SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_int; D) SHOW INDEX FROM catalog_product_entity; E) SHOW INDEX FROM catalog_category_product_index_store1; F) SHOW INDEX FROM catalog_product_entity_int;  and Welcome To magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks appreciated the response, our server is running on SSD's and here is the data requested 
https://pastebin.com/CQNZQcBT
https://imagebin.ca/v/5SzqAm0z4nR0

Comment: Thank you for the htop posted and SSD detail.  Please consider posting additional details requested for analysis.  I can see from the htop report your 8 cpu's were all busy with mysqld.

Comment: Apologies did I miss a result in the above Pastebin
pastebin.com/CQNZQcBT

Comment: Analysis in process. Thanks for the complete data requested.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your 1st query); followed by immediate SHOW WARNINGS;   so we can see any warnings raised and how the optimizer dealt with your query for processing.

Comment: Sure thing https://pastebin.com/sgQnf1R9

Comment: Lachlan-Hutchinson pastebin.com content no longer available.  Was not notified when posted.  @nameofperson will cause us to be alerted when you make additional data available for consideration.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours digging I've realised that I have followed the recommendation of query_cache_type = 0 from MySQLTunerScript as that feature would be removed in Mysql 8.0

By setting query_cache_type = 1 and tuning the query_cache_size value we have now removed the issue.

Comment: Lachlan, If any of the comments were helpful, please upvote them.  If any Answer was helpful, please Upvote and if it was the BEST answer, mark Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid data-type conversions, try this query, please

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id=10
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = 99) AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = 99) AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = 97) AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = 97) AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) = 4) AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = 1)

```
and compare timings to completion for selecting the same data with the single quotes removed on 6 equal selectors.
```

Please post timings before and after to select the ~ 162450 distinct count.

Workload analysis in process, give me another day, please for config suggestions to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your RDS Parameters group

```
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 1 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 38,718 faster
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
read_rnd_buffer_size=64K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 104,614
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 329,982
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.

For additional assistance, please view my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Your SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST indicated ~ 130 of the processes were stalled at SENDING DATA SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT .... let's determine why, please.